# Is it possible to add an app to the native share dialog?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am assuming it is not possible to add apps to the native share dialog, like the one used in the Camera Roll. However I see screenshots around with different apps in the dialog.

[image]
[image]

Is it only apps that are integrated in the OS that can be in this dialog? Or is it possible with some scheme or something?

Comment: I assume there's some sort of badge you're going for by creating an iOS9 tag first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have researched the possibilities of `UIDocumentInteractionController` mentioned by 'The Tiger' and came to the conclusion that it is not possible.

I have looked at the Apple Documentation, declaring the Document Types in the info.plist works for other apps but not for Mail, Images / Camera Roll / etc; the native share dialogs.

Edit:
I really don't get the downvotes....
Here are some references that say it is not possible:

- https://devforums.apple.com/thread/140939?tstart=0
- [why-cant-i-register-my-ios-application-to-handle-the-image-file-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197757/why-cant-i-register-my-ios-application-to-handle-the-image-file-type)
- [register-app-to-open-image-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481534/register-app-to-open-image-files)
- [associate-audio-and-video-types-with-iphone-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523723/associate-audio-and-video-types-with-iphone-app)
- [add-a-file-association-with-tiff-files-on-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094088/add-a-file-association-with-tiff-files-on-ios)
- [associate-image-file-types-utis-with-ios-app-doesnt-show-open-in-in-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401144/associate-image-file-types-utis-with-ios-app-doesnt-show-open-in-in-m)

Comment: I downvoted because your answer is wrong in the general case, where CFBundleDocumentTypes works fine. It only fails with certain file types, e.g images. Your question was not specific to images.

Comment: The question is about 'to add apps to the native share dialog, like the one used in the Camera Roll', how is that not specific to images and videos? There are no other share dialogs afaik

Comment: Apple doesn't use the term "native share dialog". If you invent your own terminology, don't be surprised if ther are misunderstandings. It seems that pretty much everybody who replied to your question assumed that you were referring to the options menu of UIDocumentInteractionController. Instead, you meant the specific sheet of the Camera Roll shown in the screenshot. Probably this happened as you used wording that implies that this is only an example. I'm going to edit the question to make it more clear what you are looking for. But probably the question should be closed as duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass UIActivity to achieve this.
Theres an example for Dropbox:
https://github.com/goosoftware/GSDropboxActivity

Comment: I think the example you provided creates an in-app share dialog, but I want the add my app to the native share dialog

Answer (score -1):

Register your app as supporting the file types that you want to open and add the code to open them. See [Document Interaction Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403).

Comment: I have looked at the documentation, still no help. Please provide more information or examples that specifically add apps to the native share dialog (not the general dialog in other apps)